# Calculating sum of 'total' from orders table for specific store when storeID stored in either orders or customers table

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2

Here's the scenario: I've got an orders table and a customers table. I'd like to calculate the SUM of the column `total` for specific `storeID`. The problem is that my company used to store the `storeID` in the `customers` table but now it's being stored in the `orders` table. There are orders in our database where the `storeID` is *only* set in the `customers` table, *only* set in the `orders` table, or set in *both* tables.

Here's some schema example data for reference:

Table `Orders`:

```
+----+-------+------------+---------+
| id | total | customerID | storeID |
+----+-------+------------+---------+
|  0 |   100 |          1 | 1       |
|  1 |    50 |          1 | NULL    |
|  2 |    75 |          1 | 1       |
+----+-------+------------+---------+
```

Table `Customers`:

```
+----+----------+
| id | storeID  |
+----+----------+
|  1 | 1 | NULL |
+----+----------+
```

The query I've been playing around with trying to calculate the sum of the order total looks like this:

```
SELECT SUM(total)
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN customers c
        ON c.ID = o.customerID
WHERE ISNULL(c.storeID,o.storeID) = @storeID
```

This query works, but it's super slow because we have so many order records in our database. Is there a more efficient way to do this? I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: If there was an instance where the storeID is set on both the customer record, and one of the customer's orders, would doing a union cause the order total to be added twice to the sum?

Comment: What happens if the `storeId` doesn't match between `Order` and `Customer`?  You could be getting two potentially different results - 1) All orders for all customers who have (ever) shopped at a particular store 2) All orders at a given store.

Comment: @marc_s Sorry, 2008 R2. I was thinking Visual Studio 2010

Comment: What kind of indexes do you have on your tables?

Comment: Don't see any indexes related to the storeID column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(total)
FROM orders o
WHERE coalesce(o.storeID, (
                    select storeID
                    from customers
                    where id = o.customerID
                ) = @storeID
```

BTW you can just update the orders table and after that query from there only:

```
update orders o
set storeID = (
        select storeID
        from customers
        where id = o.customerID
        )
where storeID is null
```